# Routing error on new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an index.html.haml generated from a new scaffold that is giving me an error when I try click on the new record link.

The error is;

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"}

What is confusing me is why is the action "show" and not "new"?

I've compared it to a working scaffold and it all looks okay.

Here is the haml view code;

```
= link_to 'New Account', new_account_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

The entry in the routes file:

```
  resources :accounts
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.8.

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be that link that's causing the problem - in the new view, or the _form partial, do you have anywhere that's trying to generate a link to account_path without passing in an account?

Comment: What `href` does that link have in your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks cheeseweasel, I had account_path instead of accounts_path in the form.